# Visual Studio 2012 Resharper menu not show

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I installed Resharper-10 for VS2012, but the menu RESHARPER doesn't show.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\VS-Version.0_Config in Windows registry. Delete the complete branch.

Comment: Is this just registry digging or do you have some source you obtained this from.